# How to count results from many GAE tasks?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I run many-many tasks to get some information and process it. After each task run, I have an integer, which indicates how many portions of the information I've got.
I would like to get sum of these integers received from different tasks.

Currently I use memcache to store sum:

```
def update_memcache_value(what, val, how_long=86400):
    value_old = get_memcache_value(what)
    memcache.set('system_'+what, value_old+val, how_long)

def get_memcache_value(what):
    value = memcache.get('system_'+what)
    if not value:
        value = 0
    return int(value)
```

`update_memcache_value` is called within each task (quite more often than once). But looks like the data there is often lost during the day. I can use NDB to store the same data, but it will require a lot of write ops. Is there any better way to store the same data (counter)?

Comment: Isn't NDB write-back? So I'm not sure what you could do that would be more efficient. You can't avoid writing *somewhere* every time you update the value, and you can't avoid writing cache->mem if it's going to be flushed and you need persistence.

Comment: Use appengine-pipelines and/or appengine-mapreduce.

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi, will not I face with the same NDB limits with Pipelines (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-pipelines/wiki/Python) usage?

Comment: I think that your goal to minimize your costs should be to process as much data as possible within single task.

Comment: Your question is too broad.  There are many ways to tally the counters but they involve different approaches.  Please edit your question to focus on one approach.

Comment: There are many options, but you could stick your increments on a pull queue and write an aggregate figure with a cron job. Also, if you have different tasks modifying the same memcache object, you should use [atomic counters](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/functions#Client_incr).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are specifically looking to have many tasks do a part of a sum and then have those all reduce down to one number at the end... so you want to use MapReduce.  Or you could just use Pipelines, as MapReduce is actually built on top of it.  If you're worried about write-ops, then you aren't going to be able to take advantage of App Engine's parallelism

**Google I/O 2010 - Data pipelines with Google App Engine**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSDC_TU7rtc

**Pipelines Library**

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-pipelines/wiki

**MapReduce**

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if your tasks span throughout the day memcache is not an option.

If you want to reduce the write ops you could set a second counter and backup the value on memcache every 100 tasks or whatever works for you.

if you are expecting to do this with using write ops for every task you could try backing up those results in a 3rd party storage like for example a Google Spreadsheet through the [Spreasheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets) but it seems like an overkill just to save some write ops (and not as performant, which is guess is not an issue).